# How to backup Viber messages?

Tags: apps, backup, messaging, viber

Is there any way at all to backup Viber messages on Windows Phones?

[The standard backup feature on Viber](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1334452-how-to-create-a-backup-file-of-your-messages) is currently only available for iPhone and Android.

Any workarounds to backup Viber messages?

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

1. move Viber to SD card
2. backup Viber folder
3. restore database from Viber folder (LocalState\DB\viber.db)

Comment: I have the app installed on SD Card. Where can I find the Viber folder there?

Answer (score 1):

Photos from VIber are in Pictures\Viber.